# What exactly is meant by 'sentence' and 'expression'?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Most introductory logic textbooks that I have skimmed through in a while, keep the terms 'sentence' and 'expression' undefined.

I would intuitively see

> Earth is round.
>
> Why didn't Harry come to the party?
>
> Come here, Harry!
>
> *x* lives in Norway.

all as sentences. However, '*x* lives in Norway' is usually not taken to be a sentence in logic because it contains a variable. It rather gives sentences after variables have been replaced by constants.

It seems to me that the term 'expression' has a broader meaning and sentences are special cases of expressions. But still what exactly is an expression? Would

> arh ahfb hghd udh

be an expression? Would 'arh', 'udh', etc. be expressions? If  'arh ahfb hghd udh'  is an expression , would it be a sentence? Is it necessary for an expression to have a meaning? All these troubles imo are stemming from a lack of definition of terms 'sentence' and 'expression'.

How exactly can we define these terms?

Comment: Instead of skimming, why not read the book more carefully? I have never seen a mathematical logic book that does not define these.

Comment: I was following one book dedicatedly while only referring to others in need and I couldn't really find these terms defined in any, but used repeatedly to define other terms, right from the start. Do you recommend any?

Comment: My first book was "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" by Herb Enderton but Schoenfeld's "Mathematical Logic" is also good. There are also some pdfs available online. You should look for a book on mathematical logic to avoid philosophical discussions which may not cover the material. To be honest, I have no experience with books on logic from a philosopher's perspective.

Comment: In your book, look for the section on well formed formulas or maybe just formulas.

Comment: In natural languages anyway, the truth value (true or false) of many sentences are indeterminate, e.g. questions, imperatives. In other words, the truth value of a sentence in natural language will be one of either true, false or indeterminate. Sentences which are true iff they are false would then be of indeterminate, e.g. "This sentence is false."

Comment: We can't comment on "most introductory logic textbooks" as different authors take different approaches. Please cite a specific textbook and a specific problem that you have with it.

Answer (score 2):

A preliminary observation. From the time of Aristotle, logicians have used a ‘divide and conquer’ strategy that involves introducing simplified, tightly-disciplined, languages. For Aristotle, his regimented language was a fragment of *very* stilted Greek; for us, our regimented languages are entirely artificial formal constructions. But either way, the plan is that we tackle  a stretch of reasoning by reformulating it in a suitable  regimented language with clear definitions of what count as sentences and other types of expression, with much tidier  logical operators, etc., and *then* we can evaluate  the reasoning once recast into this more well-behaved form. This way, we have a division of labour. First, we clarify the intended structure of the original argument by rendering  it into an unambiguous simplified/formalized language. Second, there's the separate business of assessing the validity of the resulting  regimented argument.

The point of going formal, then, is precisely to sidestep messy questions about ordinary language such as “exactly what makes for a sentence?”. For when we turn to formalized languages we can of course give precise definitions of various kinds of expressions, of which sequences of expressions constitute well-formed formulas, and of which well-formed formulas are sentences.

So short answer: logicians just don't need to worry too much e.g. about what counts as a sentence of *ordinary* language.

Comment: Expressions are built up recursively from atoms and terms and sentences are expressions without free variables. These are rigorously defined in any text on mathematical logic.

Comment: @Douma Exactly. But being charitable I take the OP to have perhaps got worried about the preliminary chat you often get in intro logic books before they go formal, chat about informal arguments. Hence my response.